# How to know documentation belongs to which version in angular.io site?

Tags: angular

I am working on an Angular 4 project, and recently Angular 5.2 is released.

When I open angular.io site and click on "Docs", I am able to see the documentation for Angular, but nowhere mentioned about what is the version of that documentation.

I have seen in some version that ngClass is used in brackets like [ngClass] and in some other version as ngClass, but dont know which version has what syntax.

Why there is no such information in angular.io site and how to get the documentation for angular 4 in angular.io site, please let me know

Answer (score 1):

You can visit https://v4.angular.io/docs for Angular 4 docs, and the ngClass API you are looking for is in https://v4.angular.io/api/common/NgClass. For other versions, you can click through white button (which opens up different release versions) on the left navigation bar on https://angular.io/.